# Are float inequalities guaranteed to be consistent

Tags: c++, c, floating-point

Assume `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are declared `double` (or `float`). Are the following expressions always true?

```
! ( (a >= b) && (c <= d) ) || ( (a-c) >= (b-d) )

! ( (a >  b) && (c <= d) ) || ( (a-c) >  (b-d) )

! ( (a >= b) && (c <  d) ) || ( (a-c) >  (b-d) )
```

Is there any guaranty from the IEEE 754 or the current C or C++ standard? And will any compiler optimize this as simply true at compile time? I am interested mostly in normal values, not so much in subnormal or special values.

Seems to me this should depend on round-off errors during subtraction mostly.

Comment: "will any compiler optimize this as simply true at compile time" – why don't you try it?

Comment: @101010 "when `a != b` their representing bits are also different" – wrong. (+0 and -0, NaN, etc.)

Comment: Can the compiler know the values of a,b,c and d at compile time?

Comment: @A B: The values of the variables should be irrelevant, because for real numbers, these expressions are always true.

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant: I tried some gcc and clang versions, they all spit out a lot of FPU instructions.

Comment: @temple: Even if they were always-true, collapsing them out would not be a valid transformation (optimization) because they can affect the state of the floating point exception flags.

Comment: @R.. That would mean a compiler can never remove a floating point operation because it could've triggered a floating point exception? I hope that's not true otherwise C has a big problem.

Comment: @Jerem: That's not exactly the right statement, but close, and it's true of any language that implements IEEE arithmetic properly. If you don't want to perform the operation, don't write it. Even without exceptions, algebraic transformations of floating point expressions are almost all invalid because floating point almost completely lacks algebraic structure. So I'm quite serious when I say that if you're going to use floating point, you have to write exactly what you mean.

Comment: @R: To me they seem trivially true for NaNs.

Comment: @temple: Indeed, I missed the `!`'s when I wrote that. Deleting the comment.

Comment: @R.. "why don't you try it?" is a perfectly valid response to a question asking whether or not it will be optimized by any compiler. If OP tries it and it is optimized, he has a definite "yes" answer, else he can proceed asking (mentioning the efforts he already made to find the answer to his question).

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: Well gcc with `-ffast-math` *might* optimize it, but then that's arguably not "a C compiler"... :-)

Comment: @Jerem the compiler won't even optimize simple things like `x == x`, `x -= 0` or `x *= 2` out, because floating-point numbers aren't real numbers and the properties don't hold. It'll emit a multiplication and an addition for `a += b*c` even though a single FMA instruction will be faster and more accurate. You must explicitly call FMA yourself. [Floating Point Optimization#Not all algebraic idioms are valid](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Floating_Point_Optimization#Not_all_algebraic_idioms_are_valid)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Ok, but that has nothing to do with cases where floating points operations remain because they may trigger floating point exceptions. Fortunately for us, a compiler will still optimize out `true || ((a-c) > (b-d))` (I checked).

Comment: @Jerem: That's dead code removal and has nothing to do with floating point. It's not removed because it's always-true but because the code path containing the floating point is unreachable. Executing it would be just as invalid as executing it in this form: `if (0) { ((a-c)>(b-d)) }`

Answer (score 10):

For the 3rd to produce false it should be sufficient to take large equal `a` and `b` and small unequal `c` and `d`, e.g. `a=1e30, b=1e30, c=1e-31, d=1e-30`.

EDIT: Ok, for the 2nd to produce false, by analogy to the 3rd, it should be sufficient to take small unequal `a` and `b` and large equal `c` and `d`, e.g. `a=1e-30, b=1e-31, c=1e30, d = 1e30`.

No idea about a counterexample for the 1st expression...

Comment: Right, only number one stands.

Comment: I suspect it's not possible to choose values that make #1 false.

Comment: Setting a b c and d to +Infinity yields false for #1 [demo](http://ideone.com/oXmPXP), although I guess that doesn't count because it's a "special" value

Comment: @mch, odd, that was supposed to be 1f/0f. Seems like I linked to a previous version

Comment: @R.., at least we don't know how to select values making #1 false using the same approach as I used. Maybe there is another nuance/idea for making #1 false, or there is a proof that #1 gives consistent results.

Answer (score 7):

Serge Rogatch gave counterexamples to your second and third expressions.

The first one, `!(a >= b && c <= d) || a-c >= b-d`, is always true in IEEE 754 arithmetic, if `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` must all be finite.  Subtraction of finite numbers cannot produce a `NaN`.  Thus a counterexample must satisfy `a >= b && c <= d && a-c < b-d`.  However, `a >= b` implies that `a-c >= b-c`, whatever `c` is, and `c <= d` implies that `b-c >= b-d`, whatever `b` is.  Transitivity of `>=` takes care of the rest.

You can take `a = c = 1.0/0.0` and take arbitrary choices of `b` and `d` for a counterexample if you relax the condition that `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` must all be finite.  All counterexamples are of essentially this form.

Comment: "However, a >= b implies that a-c >= b-c, whatever c is, and c <= d implies that b-c >= b-d, whatever b is." - How can we be sure that this assumption is true?

Comment: @temple: If a and b are finite, c can be -oo, finite, or oo.  If c is -oo, then a - c == oo and b - c = oo.  If c is oo, then a - c = -oo and b - c = -oo.  If c is finite, then, before rounding, a-c >= b-c.  Rounding preserves >=.